# Code First: Generate mapping table for 1-many relation

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EFCore and have the following models:

```
public class Visit
    {
        [Key]
        public int VisitId { get; set; }
        public DateTime VisitDate {get;set;}
        public string Description {get;set;}
        public List<Procedure> Procedures {get;set;}
    }

public class Procedure
    {
      [Key]
      public int ProcedureId {get;set;}
      public string ProcedureName {get;set;}
    }
```

Each visit can have multiple Procedures hence List in the Visit class. Procedure class is independent, with no parent or child, it is used to define Procedures in the system.

The problem is that EFCore, instead of creating a mapping table that maps each Visit to a number of Procedures, creates a relation between the Procedure table and the Visit table by adding a column in the Procedure table.

I can create a new class that defines this relation which would have two foreign keys from each of these classes, but I want to know how to make EFCore handle this so that it creates the new relation table and also loads data accordingly ie for every Visit, all Procedures are loaded. Or I must create that class manually to define the relation to EFCore?

Comment: What you really ask is how to generate a mapping table for a 1:Many relation, even though it's not needed. When there's only one possible value, the easiest way is to use an extra FK column, not create a new table. That's the strategy Code-First uses. To use a mapping table you'd have to ensure only the PK column had a unique index, otherwise you'd end with a many-to-many relation

Comment: Yes, a mapping table must be produced. Also, why is EFCore assuming that there is only one possible value, when the List<Procedure> indicates there could be multiple Procedures for each Visit?

Comment: Because the code says so. There are many Procedures per Visit but only one possible Visit value for every Procedure. That's what 1-Many means. Is the relation many-to-many perhaps? In that case `Procedure` should have a `Visits` property

Comment: I suspect you really want a M:N relation: dentist visits where multiple procedures may be performed. You're trying to use `Procedure` as a lookup type though. Generating the *table* from that type won't produce the many-to-many relation. Besides, won't you want to find how many fillings were performed in a month? You'll need a `Procedure.Visits` at this point.

Comment: If `Procedure` is really independent, then you need many-to-many as mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos. You can find in docs how to map/configure link table with just one navigation property, if that's the problem (by default it is mapped to one-to-many, so some fluent config is needed).

Comment: If each unique visit has many procedures, why would it be a many to many? Shouldn't it be one visit - many procedures?

Comment: I looked at this answer and tried this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401290/how-do-i-map-to-a-lookup-table-using-entity-framework-code-first-with-fluent-api But this does not produce the mapping table as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using and what did you actually try? That's a 9 year old answer about EF, not EF Core, but this *does* work in recent EF Core versions. EF Core added automatic join table generation in recent versions - either 5 or 6. In the [Many-to-many docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) you see that `Post.Tags` and `Tag.Posts` result in a `PostTags` table without a join type. What did you actually try?

Comment: *Shouldn't it be one visit - many procedures?* No, that would mean that each procedure  would be dedicated to one and only one visit (1-to-N is also N-to-**1**). Just try adding a `Visits` property to `Procedure` (`List<Visit>`) and see how EF generates the data model. When you see it, you'll understand.